# Javascript/Wordpress - Form selection conditions

Tags: javascript, wordpress, conditional-statements, html-select

Javascript newbie here. I've got the following partially working code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $("#frm_form_70_container input[type=submit]").css('visibility', 'hidden'); //hide submit button by default

    $("select[name='item_meta[4418]'], select[name='item_meta[4473]'], select[name='item_meta[4474]'], select[name='item_meta[4483]']").change(function () {
        var submit = true;

        if ($("select[name='item_meta[4418]']:selected").val() == 'Email' || $("select[name='item_meta[4473]']:selected").val() == 'Email' || $("select[name='item_meta[4474]']:selected").val() == 'Email' || $("select[name='item_meta[4483]']:selected").val() == 'Email')

        submit = false;

        if (submit) {
            $("#frm_form_70_container input[type=submit]").css('visibility', 'visible');
        } else {
            $("#frm_form_70_container input[type=submit]").css('visibility', 'hidden');
        }

    });
});
```

I've got a drop down box with a few values. What I want to happen is for the submit button to hide when anything other than the value "Email" is selected.

This probably seems foolish and I apologize, but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: why `var submit=true; if(something) submit=false; if(submit) ...` instead of just `if(!something) ...`? Also, if you would provide the relevant DOM it would be helpful... preferably in a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Could you please post your html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Courtesy of mainly @smerny and myself

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    var $allSelects = $("#frm_form_70_container").find('select'),
        $submitBtn = $("#frm_form_70_container input[type=submit]");

    $allSelects.on('change', function () {
        if (!$allSelects.filter(function() { 
            return this.value === "Email"; }).length) {
            $submitBtn.hide();
        } else {
            $submitBtn.show();
        }

    });
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dcodesmith/9uJxP/)**

Comment: This code worked. I had to change the CSS style, but other than that it seems to work great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've taken the code that @dcodesmith and @smerny suggested but I need to add another option like " return this.value === "Apply for Senior Forecaster";" see here: http://jsfiddle.net/2oajog5x/

I'm not that familiar with JS unfortunately.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  var $allSelects = $("#frm_form_11_container").find('select'),
    $submitBtn = $("#frm_form_11_container input[type=submit]");

  $allSelects.change(function() {
    if (!$allSelects.filter(function() {
        return this.value === "Apply for Senior Forecaster";
      }).length) {
      $submitBtn.hide();
    } else {
      $submitBtn.show();
    }

  });
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form id='frm_form_11_container'>
  <select>
    <option value="What do you want to do?">What do you want to do?</option>
    <option value="Apply for Senior Forecaster">Apply for Senior Forecaster</option>
    <option value="I'd like to talk about a position">I'd like to talk about a position</option>
  </select>
```